# Remove <div> and <span> tag

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor4

I am using CKEditor 4.19.1.
If I drag and copy and paste the contents containing the  and  tag on another website, the  and  tag disappear.

When tested by version, 4.4.8 version is normally copied and paste, but and tags are deleted from Starting with 4.5.X version

The configuration below does not work.

```
config.allowedContent = true;
config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre;div';
config.extraAllowedContent = 'div';
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer
The answer was the pasteFilter setting.

```
config.pasteFilter = null;
```

Normal operation started after this setting